Flatpak how to include libusb-1.0
I'm trying to write an app using Gnome Builder to control my computer's LED lights.. However, my code requires the use of libusb-1.0. For the life of me I can't figure out how to include it in my flatpak app. I've added my dependency to my meson.build, but I get the following error:
Run-time dependency libusb-1.0 found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)

../../../../../../Drive/project/src/meson.build:11:2: ERROR: Dependency "libusb-1.0" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake

I've tried adding the library source in my manifest.json, but I can't get it work either.
manifest:
{
    "id" : "org.gnome.app1",
    "runtime" : "org.gnome.Platform",
    "runtime-version" : "master",
    "sdk" : "org.gnome.Sdk",
    "command" : "app1",
    "finish-args" : [
        "--share=network",
        "--share=ipc",
        "--socket=fallback-x11",
        "--device=dri",
        "--socket=wayland"
    ],
    "cleanup" : [
        "/include",
        "/lib/pkgconfig",
        "/man",
        "/share/doc",
        "/share/gtk-doc",
        "/share/man",
        "/share/pkgconfig",
        "*.la",
        "*.a"
    ],
    "modules" : [
             {
            "name" : "app1",
            "builddir" : true,
            "buildsystem" : "meson",
            "sources" : [
                {
                    "type" : "git",
                    "url" : "file:///home/user/projects"
                }
            ]
        },
         {
            "name" : "libusb-1.0",
            "builddir" : true,
            "buildsystem" : "cmake",
            "sources" : [
                {
                    "type" : "archive",
                    "url" : "https://github.com/libusb/libusb/releases/download/v1.0.27/libusb-1.0.27.tar.bz2"
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}

root meson.build:
project('app1', 'c',
          version: '0.1.0',
    meson_version: '>= 0.62.0',
  default_options: [ 'warning_level=2', 'werror=false', 'c_std=gnu11', ],
)

i18n = import('i18n')
gnome = import('gnome')
cc = meson.get_compiler('c')

config_h = configuration_data()
config_h.set_quoted('PACKAGE_VERSION', meson.project_version())
config_h.set_quoted('GETTEXT_PACKAGE', 'app1')
config_h.set_quoted('LOCALEDIR', get_option('prefix') / get_option('localedir'))
configure_file(output: 'config.h', configuration: config_h)
add_project_arguments(['-I' + meson.project_build_root()], language: 'c')

project_c_args = []
test_c_args = [
  '-Wcast-align',
  '-Wdeclaration-after-statement',
  '-Werror=address',
  '-Werror=array-bounds',
  '-Werror=empty-body',
  '-Werror=implicit',
  '-Werror=implicit-function-declaration',
  '-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types',
  '-Werror=init-self',
  '-Werror=int-conversion',
  '-Werror=int-to-pointer-cast',
  '-Werror=main',
  '-Werror=misleading-indentation',
  '-Werror=missing-braces',
  '-Werror=missing-include-dirs',
  '-Werror=nonnull',
  '-Werror=overflow',
  '-Werror=parenthesis',
  '-Werror=pointer-arith',
  '-Werror=pointer-to-int-cast',
  '-Werror=redundant-decls',
  '-Werror=return-type',
  '-Werror=sequence-point',
  '-Werror=shadow',
  '-Werror=strict-prototypes',
  '-Werror=trigraphs',
  '-Werror=undef',
  '-Werror=write-strings',
  '-Wformat-nonliteral',
  '-Wignored-qualifiers',
  '-Wimplicit-function-declaration',
  '-Wlogical-op',
  '-Wmissing-declarations',
  '-Wmissing-format-attribute',
  '-Wmissing-include-dirs',
  '-Wmissing-noreturn',
  '-Wnested-externs',
  '-Wno-cast-function-type',
  '-Wno-dangling-pointer',
  '-Wno-missing-field-initializers',
  '-Wno-sign-compare',
  '-Wno-unused-parameter',
  '-Wold-style-definition',
  '-Wpointer-arith',
  '-Wredundant-decls',
  '-Wstrict-prototypes',
  '-Wswitch-default',
  '-Wswitch-enum',
  '-Wundef',
  '-Wuninitialized',
  '-Wunused',
  '-fno-strict-aliasing',
  ['-Werror=format-security', '-Werror=format=2'],
]
if get_option('buildtype') != 'plain'
  test_c_args += '-fstack-protector-strong'
endif
foreach arg: test_c_args
  if cc.has_multi_arguments(arg)
    project_c_args += arg
  endif
endforeach
add_project_arguments(project_c_args, language: 'c')

subdir('data')
subdir('src')
subdir('po')

gnome.post_install(
     glib_compile_schemas: true,
    gtk_update_icon_cache: true,
  update_desktop_database: true,
)

src meson.build
app1_sources = [
  'main.c',
  'app1-application.c',
  'app1-window.c'
]

app1_deps = [
  dependency('gtk4'),
  dependency('libadwaita-1', version: '>= 1.4'),
  dependency('libusb-1.0')
]

app1_sources += gnome.compile_resources('app1-resources',
  'app1.gresource.xml',
  c_name: 'app1'
)

executable('app1', app1_sources,
  dependencies: app1_deps,
       install: true,
)


The correct approach is to add the lib as a dependency in your manifest. What error occurs when you try to run the project with the lib added to the manifest? Another thing, access to USB depends on permissions, you have to grant those permissions.

The correct way to do this is:
{
    "name": "libusb",
    "config-opts": [ "--disable-static" ],
    "cleanup": [
        "/lib/*.la",
        "/lib/pkgconfig",
        "/include"
    ],
    "sources": [
        {
            "type": "archive",
            "url": "https://github.com/libusb/libusb/releases/download/v1.0.27/libusb-1.0.27.tar.bz2",
            "sha256": "ffaa41d741a8a3bee244ac8e54a72ea05bf2879663c098c82fc5757853441575"
        }
    ],
    "post-install": [
        "install -Dm644 COPYING ${FLATPAK_DEST}/share/licenses/libusb/COPYING"
    ]
}

